# Odin does not Detect "Samsung Galaxy Note 3"

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, samsung-galaxy-note-3, odin

I'm trying to upgrade the firmware from `4.3` to `4.4.2` or even `5.0`.

But; `Odin` *does not detect it* !

Is there a way for fix it?

Comment: Odin only recognizes a device when it's in download mode.  Have you rebooted your Note 3 to Download mode?  You do this by turning the phone off, and then turning it on while holding Power + Home + Vol Down buttons together.  When a Warning message pops up, press the Vol Up button.  Now connect the phone to your computer via USB, and assuming you have Samsung's drivers installed Odin should recognize the phone.

Comment: I´ve done exactly what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download `Samsung Driver` With below links :

> http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads
>
> http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201406/20140624231220544/SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones_v1.5.45.0.exe

Or Download `Samsung Kies`.

Comment: Thank you! Downloaded drivers again. Problem remains, equally Kies does not detect this unit, Windows detects, so it´s files can be seen with file manager. When started with Home+Power+Volume Down buttons to "Download mode", shows chinese text!

Comment: hey ron.can you take a picture ?

Comment: A picture of chinese text?

Comment: yes sir.or ask a question with that for other helps and ...`http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask`

Comment: I found a video that shows the chinese text (at 1mins 40 secs) exactly same than in my phone. The phone in the video can be factory reseted pressing home (Vol UP in my phone) button on the text "XXX eMMC". Yes, it resets the thing, but still it Odin does not work!

the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tdc5SnSmx1I

Comment: Can you try this with another `Usb Port` or another Pc ? test it with `main usb port` and disconnect another usb cables.